# AJAX onkeyup event trigger in php code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, search-engine

I am a newbie in AJAX script and javascript. I am using AJAX to get search suggestion when the user type the first letter in the search box. But after typing the AJAX and javascript code, I could not get any suggestion coming out below the search box. I wonder if someone could help me to fix this problem?

By the way, I hope that the suggestion limit would be 5. How can I do this?

Code for index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Brandon's Search Engine
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #suggestion {
                border: 1px solid black;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            #suggestion a {
                font-size: 12pt;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                width: 450px;
                height: auto;
            }
            #suggestion a:hover {
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getSuggestion(q) {
            var ajax;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)//for ie7+, FF, Chrome
                ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();//ajax object
            else
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//for ie6 and previous
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function {
                if(ajax.status == 200 && ajax.readyState == 4) {
                    document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                }
            }
            ajax.open("GET", "suggestion.php?q=$query" + q, false);
            ajax.send();
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="search.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="0" />
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1><center>Brandon's Search Engine</center></h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="text" name="q" size="90"
                               onkeyup="getSuggestion(q)" autocomplete="off" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <div id="suggestion" size="90">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code for suggestion.php:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'; //connect with database
$query = $_GET["q"];
if($query != "")
{
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE title LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' OR link LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' LIMIT 0 , 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$stmt) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$number_of_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($number_of_result < 1) {
    echo "Your search did not match any documents. Please try different keywords.";
} else {
    //results found here and display them
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))//show first 10 results
        $title = $row["title"];
        $link = $row["link"];
        echo "<div id='sugg-search-result'>";
        echo "<a href='$link' id='sugg-title'>" . $title . "</a>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by changing `onreadystatechange = function {` to `onreadystatechange = function(){`. Also in `"suggestion.php?q=$query"`, `$query` would be the `$_GET['q']` value.

Comment: In function `getSuggestion(q) {` `q` becomes the Event Object, when you assign it to `onkeyup=`.

Comment: What do you mean by `Also in "suggestion.php?q=$query", $query would be the $_GET['q'] value` and `In function getSuggestion(q) { q becomes the Event Object, when you assign it to onkeyup=.`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing php delimiter's here.

Change this:

```
ajax.open("GET", "suggestion.php?q=$query" + q, false);
```

To:

```
ajax.open("GET", "suggestion.php?q=<?php echo $query;?>"+q, false);
```

**Updated answer:**

In the `keyup` function, the parameter your passing is incorrect.

```
<input type="text" name="q" size="90" onkeyup="getSuggestion(q)" autocomplete="off" />
```

Instead pass the value what has been typed:

```
<input type="text" name="q" size="90" onkeyup="getSuggestion(this.value)" autocomplete="off" />
```

Change this:

```
ajax.open("GET", "suggestion.php?q=$query" + q, false);
```

To:

```
ajax.open("GET", "suggestion.php?q="+q, false);
```

**jQuery ajax:**

```
function getSuggestion(q){
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "suggestion.php",
  data: {item:q},
  success:function(data){
  alert(data);
  $("#suggestion").html(data);
  }
  });

}
```

**suggestion.php:**

```
$value = $_GET['item'];

// enter the query here and echo the results
```

**Note:** Do not forget to include jQuery library.

Comment: Other than this, do I have any more errors in my code. The suggestion still does not appears.

Comment: Suggestion list still unable to appear after changing. Why do I have to put "this.value" instead of "q"?

Comment: `q` is not declared nor assigned with any value.So javascript will consider it as undefined.whereas `this.value` will pass the value what has been typed at that particulat instance..

Comment: What do you mean by alerting the response?

Comment: I have refresh the page but suggestion still cannot come out

Comment: `alert(ajax.responseText);` after `innerHTML`

Comment: There is no response and it is just as same as before.

Comment: as @PHPglue said Change `onreadystatechange = function {` to `onreadystatechange = function(){`

Comment: Can you guide me to fix it? I am really a newbie in this.

Comment: It is ok for me to wait. But please help me when you are free.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. If it is me, my reputation does not allow me to.

Comment: Can you please guide me to fix my coding problem?

Comment: Iam not blaming you buddy..Chill..I recommend you go through jquery ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Am I using jquery? Is ajax equals to jquery?

Comment: No your not..your using traditional javascript ajax..Check the link which i sent you..that's jquery ajax..

Comment: Can you help me to get the whole code done? I still do not know what to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this:

```
// some common external JavaScript - learn now - common.js
//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
var IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
bod.className = 'js';
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
//]]>

// this page external JavaScript - thispage.js
//<![CDATA[
var q = E(q);
function getSuggestion(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
      E('suggestion').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', 'suggestion.php?q='+q.value, false);
  xhr.send();
}
q.onkeyup = getSuggestion;
//]]>
```

Now your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <title>
        Brandon&#039;s Search Engine
    </title>
    <style type='text/css'>
      @import 'external.css';
    </style>
  </head>
<body class='njs'>
  <form method='GET' action='search.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='page' value='0' />
    <table align='center'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h1><center>Brandon&#039;s Search Engine</center></h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <input type='text' name='q' id='q' maxlength='90' autocomplete='off' />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align='center'>
          <input type='submit' value='Search' />
          <input type='reset' value='Clear' />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <div id='suggestion'></div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='thispage.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```